# MySQL LIMIT with parameters

Tags: mysql

How to use LIMIT instruction with parameters in MySQL?

Like:

`SELECT * FROM someTable LIMIT variable1, variable2;`

Comment: Must the answer be purely SQL, or are you using a web development language, such as PHP or ASP.NET?

Comment: Purely SQL, working in MySql.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this inside SP

```
SET @String1 = concat(concat(concat(concat("SELECT field1,field2 FROM table1 WHERE field3 = ",sp_var1," && field4 = "),sp_var2," LIMIT "),sp_Var_skip,","),sp_var_count); 
PREPARE Stmt FROM @String1; 
EXECUTE Stmt; 
SET @String1 = ""
```

Alternatively

```
DELIMITER $ 
CREATE PROCEDURE `tmp`() 
BEGIN 
PREPARE STMT FROM "SELECT * FROM users LIMIT ?,?"; 
END$ 
DELIMITER; 

SET @a=2; 
SET @b=1; 

CALL tmp(); 
EXECUTE STMT USING @a, @b;
```

More information on this [here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,32292,61417#msg-61417)